# How to export extjs grid data to excel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid with large number of records. I use filters to filter the data as required. But i want to export the filtered data to a excel sheet for further usage.

I went through some articles available but they seem different and not compatible with latest 4.2 version.

Please help me in achieving this in simple manner.

Thanks much!

Comment: What you had tried so far??

Answer (score 4):

For extjs < 4
http://edspencer.net/2009/11/24/ext-ux-exporter-export-any-grid-to-excel-or-csv/

For extjs >= 4
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel

Comment: This is great, but I'm not able change the name of the file, it gets downloaded everytime as download.xls. Not getting from where its picking the filename.

Comment: Got it!! It's the download property of anchor tag where in we can set the name of the file

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this isn't possible without a Serverside implementation in a cross browser manner.

**In theory** you create a [OpenXML](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML&ei=n5PnUYS8A5D24QT65YEI&usg=AFQjCNE3rMl2P9d5C5tl0W1Am9-4g4A57g&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bGE) document string by reading the current records from the store and encode it with base64. Then write this to a `Data Uri`. The first that didn't allow inline data other then images is IE so this won't work for all IE browser version due to limitations like size and images only. This will be the reason why there are no up to date implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have implemented this as provided in the thread. But i was testing this in the IE. Now as you said i have to test this in other browsers and see what happens!

Comment: Please find the thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?32400-GridPanel-directly-to-Excel. I have tried as mentioned in the thread. But there was an error stating "reg" is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Successfully implemented [this](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/generate-an-excel-file-from-an-ext-js-4-grid/) approach for Ext JS 4. To give it a flexibility of an abstract class, follow the instructions:

1. Take functions from [here](http://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17j) and extract them into a separate class
   as global.
2. Replace all "this" function references to global function calls.
3. Add "grid" parameter to all functions starting with the entry one
   (downloadExcelXml()).
4. Replace the remaining "this" calls to grid references (as functions were expected to act inside a grid).
5. Now add this button in your grid constructor and call
   downloadExcelXml() as a handler like this:

   ```
   exportButton = {
     xtype: 'button',
     text: 'xls',
     listeners: {
       click: function (button, event, eOpts) {
         downloadExcelXml(
           false,
           "TableHeader",
           eOpts.data.grid);
       },
     data: {
       grid: this
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: Its working.. And i need one more idea, because its coming that current page results to xl. But i need the next pages also, i have put pagination for that page.