# How to export XL first and second page grid data using extjs?

Tags: php, user-interface, extjs, extjs4, export-to-excel

I am new to ExtJS and I'm using ExtJS 4.

In this I have developed export xl option but it export only the visible rows, that means the first page data only exporting but the second and other page datas not exporting.

Actually I followed to develop this export using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715833/how-to-export-extjs-grid-data-to-excel) and [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17j&view/editor).

So can any one help me to solve this.